# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, node-modules, mern

[image: the image of react app error]

Tried running all of them:

npm install @babel/core @babel/preset-env
npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack
npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react webpack
npm install -D babel-loader@7 babel-core babel-preset-env babel-preset-react webpack
npm install @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/node @babel/preset-env

Answer (score 0):

Error seems clear, *TinderCards* is already declared. What is TinderCards.css exporting that you are importing?
-`import ./TinderCards.css` maybe interpreted as importing TinderCards and so the babel parsing error.
-Also, could you share contents of ur TinderCards.css file.

npmjs.com/package/Babel#methods
This shows how Babel can help with different file formats, and your error shows that error is @babel/parser/lib... so there's error in parsing. I don't know more details of your files on all this but this may help.